# Powershell - Querying CSV column names and writing them to a new CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

So I'm trying to look at column names in a CSV, write them to an array and then spit the data back out into a new CSV with a new column attached.  I don't really care what the current data table looks like so long as I can add a column to the headers.  This seems like a fairly basic thing to be able to do but I can't seem to find any situations where anyone has done this.  For example:

```
"Name","Location","Phone"
"John Smith","Toronto","555.555.5555"
"Jane Doe","Dallas","555.555.5554"
```

I just want to keep the Name, Location and Phone column names and put them into another CSV with one extra column.  The catch is, in reality, there are more columns and they aren't always the same so the script needs to be able to be column name-agnostic.  I should be able to feed it any CSV with any number of columns with different names and be able to get an output file with just the column names.  I've tried at least a dozen different ways to do this and keep bumping into different issues.

Example:

```
$validatedfilepath = "validfile.csv"
$csvData = New-Object PSObject
$csvData = Import-CSV "file.csv" | Add-Member @{ID="$null"} -PassThru
$csvdata = $csvdata | get-member -Name * -MemberType NoteProperty
$csvData = @($csvData.Name)
$csvData
```

That will show me the exact list of column names that I want in my new validfile but I have no idea how to export it into a CSV as the column names.  Each time I've tried doing export-csv, it either gives me the character length count in a new row for each or some other goofy stuff.

Thanks

Comment: You like to create an "empty" CSV file with only the header line in it?  Whatfor? In Powershell you usually simply export structured data into a CSV file and Powershell creates the necessary headers for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What should your output csv look like?

Comment: I just noticed now that you use 2 different file names. Do you do that with a purpose?

Comment: @Olaf - I'm not actually trying to create an empty csv file but this is what I've come to.  It seems more reasonable than trying to add a new column on the fly.  I need to take the relevant columns, add the ID column and have a value added and output to a new file.  If I can at least get the column names correct, that will get me closer to my end goal.

Comment: @TToni - So the example CSV data that I showed, imagine that plus a column with data the corresponds to the row which is being modified.  I don't want to touch the original file.  The imported csv file may not have corresponding data for the new column so I want to separate those rows out into a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Export-CSV` reads the column names from the members of the input object. So you are on the right track already, you just need to simplify a bit, like this:

```
$csvData = Import-CSV "file.csv" | Add-Member @{ID="$null"} -PassThru
# You can now modify/enrich/filter the data somehow, for example like $csvdata[0].ID = 56387, then just export it:
$csvData | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "newfile.csv"
```

The error you made is overwriting the imported data in `$csvdata` with the `Get-Member` result. And then you overwrite it again with the `@($csvData.Name)` expression.

Comment: `"$null"` -> `""`

Comment: Thanks @TToni, this was the answer I needed